# Trying to load data from Parse however I keep receiving the error EXC_Brekapoint whenever I try to compile the app

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am currently trying to load data from Parse (which I realize will soon be obselete but I have to stay on it for now) and I have a custom class that is to handle all the data from the backend like so:

```
import Foundation
import Parse

class FeedContent: PFObject {

    @NSManaged var address: String
    @NSManaged var content: PFFile
    @NSManaged var isVideo: Int
    @NSManaged var attendeeObjectId: String
    @NSManaged var created: NSDate?
    @NSManaged var objId: String

    init(address: String, content: PFFile, isVideo: Int, attendeeObjectId: String, created: NSDate?, objId: String) {
        super.init()

        self.address = address
        self.content = content
        self.isVideo = isVideo
        self.attendeeObjectId = attendeeObjectId
        self.created = createdAt
        self.objId = objId

    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}

extension FeedContent: PFSubclassing {

    class func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "FeedContent"
    }

    override class func initialize() {
        var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
        dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }
}
```

and in my Display View Controller I am creating an array to house these items then calling a function to display the data , like here:

```
    func addPFObjectInFeedContent(object : PFObject) {

        let newItem = FeedContent()



        newItem.address = (object["address"] as? String)!


        newItem.isVideo = (object["isVideo"] as? Int)!

            newItem.attendeeObjectId = (object["attendeeObjectId"] as? String)!
        //newItem.eventObjectId = (object["eventObjectId"] as? String)!
        newItem.content = (object["content"] as? PFFile)!
        newItem.created = object.createdAt
        newItem.objId = object.objectId!
        self.feedContentItems.append(newItem)
    }


Here is the array as well:
  var feedContentItems = [FeedContent]()
```

On this line specifically is where the EXC_Breakpoint error occurs:

```
newItem.isVideo = (object["isVideo"] as? Int)!
```

so i was curious if anyone had any intimation of what may be happening?

```
    func loadParseFeed() {

        let contentQuery = PFQuery(className: "FeedContent")

        contentQuery.whereKey("address", equalTo: defaults.objectForKey("newLocation")! as! String)


        //contentQuery.whereKey("flagged", notEqualTo: true)
        contentQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        if blacklist.count != 0 {
            for var item = 0; item <= blacklist.count; item += 1 {
                contentQuery.whereKey("attendeeObjectId", equalTo: blacklist[item])
            }
        }
        contentQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[PFObject]?,error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                if let object = objects as [PFObject]? {

                    if objects!.count > 0 {

                        for thing in objects! {

                            //                        let newItem = FeedContent()
                            //                        newItem.isVideo = (thing["isVideo"] as? Int)!
                            //                        newItem.attendeeObjectId = (thing["attendeeObjectId"] as? String)!
                            //                        newItem.eventObjectId = (thing["eventObjectId"] as? String)!
                            //                        newItem.content = (thing["content"] as? PFFile)!
                            //                        newItem.created = thing.createdAt
                            //                        newItem.objId = thing.objectId!
                            //                        self.feedContentItems.append(newItem)

                           self.addPFObjectInFeedContent(thing)

                        }

                        self.advanceFeed()

                        //                        self.overviewTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: "advanceFeed", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                        //                        self.overviewTimer.fire()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that part of the response exists and is an int? try setting it to a specific value that would work such as 1 and then run again and see if you still get the issue

Comment: did you try to print object["isVideo"]? it is not an Int and when you are force unwrapping you just get crash, everything is working like it should

Comment: yes i have wrapped it in the form if object["isVideo"] != nil { print("\(object["isVideo"] as! Int)!") }else {    print("object could not be retrieved")} and get a value of 0 (what I have designated an image to be) in the logs

Comment: @Scriptable, I replaced it with an integer and then the next value became corrupt so I'm not sure what the issue is bc they all hold values

Comment: can you run print(object) and see what it outputs, im not very familiar with using parse

Comment: yes here's the output  <FeedContent: 0x16035c8a0, objectId: 0CkHt5SBLX, localId: (null)> {
    address = "user's address appeared here";
    attendeeObjectId = hTeHEU5nHw;
    content = "<PFFile: 0x16035cef0>";
    imgTxt = "";
    isVideo = 0;

Comment: @scriptable i think part of the issue was that I was returning values that was not particularly in the code, such as imgTxt, however even when it was included I was still recieving an error